# Selective negative image with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

Is there a way one can get a negative image, inverting all the shades of gray colors and keeping the others (white color and black color) untouched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invert them all then make whites red, blacks white and reds black.

so, if we start with this:

[image]

and do this:

```
convert input.png -negate -colorspace RGB \
  -fill red   -opaque white               \
  -fill white -opaque black               \
  -fill black -opaque red result.png
```

We get this where the inner gradient has been inverted but the outer black and white borders have not:

[image]

Comment: I am starting to fiddle with colors in images because jpg files (although they have very small sizes and this is good) but the fact is that scanned texts have somewhat poor legibility, and this is due to the fact that texts in images are usually filled with shades of gray, something which makes reading more difficult. Usually, computer fonts are all black in white brackground. For images this is great, but for scanned texts, it is kind of a challenge. Possibly this is an academic research project for someone in the future, in a college, and with great love for image manipulation.